# Summary Table of Contents in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, layout

Can I add a second table (high-level) of contents and show only H1 headings?  When I tried to add a second TOC, it seemed to just scroll down to the bottom of my existing TOC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. I just tested it in MS Word 2003 by creating different H1, H2 and H3 headings. On the first page I inserted the complete TOC, under (or onto the second page with a page break [Ctrl-Enter]) I inserted another TOC including only H1 headings, and this works correctly.

Please give it a try in another document.